# DefaultSelect typeahead reactjs with data in fetch

Tags: reactjs, axios, typeahead

I have a typeahead in which I send a series of languages ​​to a user, then I have to obtain those languages ​​and paint them in that same typeahead, DefaultSelect was an option but I can't find a way to do it with data obtained from a get
this is my code

```
 axios.get(Api + "userlanguage/getAll", {headers: headers})
        .then(response =>{
            var userlanguage = response.data.message
            if (userlanguage.length > 0) {
                for (var i in userlanguage) {
                    this.state.userlanguage = userlanguage[i]
                }
            }else{
                this.state.userlanguage = "No have language"
            }
            userlanguage = Object.values(userlanguage)
            this.setState({ userlanguage });
        })
        .catch(err =>{

        })


                           <Typeahead
                            required
                            multiple
                            labelKey='description'
                            id="my-typeahead-id"
                            renderMenuItemChildren={(option, props) => (
                                <div>
                                    <div><img className="img_language" src= {api+option.url}/>{option.description}</div>
                                </div>
                            )}
                            onChange={(selected) => {
                                var new_array = []
                                for (var i in selected) {
                                    new_array[i] = selected[i].ide
                                }
                                this.setState({new_array})
                                this.state.languages = new_array
                                }}
                                options={this.state.language}
                                defaultSelected = {userlanguage}
                                />
```

Comment: please explain brief more about your problem,we are not getting your point...

Comment: Sure, i am doing an application in which I need an autocomplete with tags, and I do an update to a user of those tags, then in the same place where I use the typeahead (which in this case is to edit the user's profile), I need to show the tags that the user previously selected (I get them from another endpoint), either to remove them or to add other ones